# Change the options in a Picker dynamically using distinct arrays

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to get a Picker to update dynamically depending on the selection of the prior Picker. In order to achieve this, I'm using a multidimensional array. Unfortunately this seems to confuse my ForEach loop and I noticed the following message in the logs:

`ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, Text> count (3) != its initial count (5).`ForEach(*:content:)`should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to`Identifiable`or use`ForEach(*:id:content:)`and provide an explicit`id`!`

This kinda makes sense, I'm guessing what is happening is that I'm passing it one array and it keeps referring to it, so as far as it is concerned, it keeps changing constantly whenever I pass it another array. I believe the way to resolve this is to use the id parameter that can be passed to ForEach, although I'm not sure this would actually solve it and I'm not sure what I would use. The other solution would be to somehow destroy the Picker and recreate it? Any ideas?

My code follows. If you run it, you'll notice that moving around the first picker can result in an out of bounds exception.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var baseNumber = ""
    @State private var dimensionSelection = 1
    @State private var baseUnitSelection = 0
    @State private var convertedUnitSelection = 0

    let temperatureUnits = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]
    let lengthUnits = ["meters", "kilometers", "feet", "yards", "miles"]
    let timeUnits = ["seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days"]
    let volumeUnits = ["milliliters", "liters", "cups", "pints", "gallons"]
    let dimensionChoices = ["Temperature", "Length", "Time", "Volume"]
    let dimensions: [[String]]

    init () {
        dimensions = [temperatureUnits, lengthUnits, timeUnits, volumeUnits]
    }

    var convertedValue: Double {

        var result: Double = 0
        let base = Double(baseNumber) ?? 0
        if temperatureUnits[baseUnitSelection] == "Celsius" {
            if convertedUnitSelection == 0 {
                result = base
            } else if convertedUnitSelection == 1 {
                result = base * 9/5 + 32
            } else if convertedUnitSelection == 2 {
                result = base + 273.15
            }
        }

        return result
    }


    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Enter a number", text: $baseNumber)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }

                Section(header: Text("Select the type of conversion")) {
                    Picker("Dimension", selection: $dimensionSelection) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< dimensionChoices.count) {
                            Text(self.dimensionChoices[$0])
                        }
                    }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                }

                Group {
                    Section(header: Text("Select the base unit")) {
                        Picker("Base Unit", selection: $baseUnitSelection) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.dimensions[self.dimensionSelection].count) {
                                Text(self.dimensions[self.dimensionSelection][$0])
                            }
                        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    }

                    Section(header: Text("Select the unit to convert to")) {
                        Picker("Converted Unit", selection: $convertedUnitSelection) {
                            ForEach(0 ..< self.dimensions[self.dimensionSelection].count) {
                                Text(self.dimensions[self.dimensionSelection][$0])
                            }
                        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                    }
                }

                Section(header: Text("The converted value is")) {
                    Text("\(convertedValue) \(dimensions[dimensionSelection][convertedUnitSelection])")
                }

            }.navigationBarTitle("Unit Converter")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a peek at Measurement. There’s no need to manually convert measurements in Swift.

Comment: I tried to solve it, first by using `ForEach` iterations through elements. One thing I found, that a binding wont set if the type of the iteration and the passed selection differs. (I think something may have to do with inferred tags, if there is such a thing). Anyway, I got stuck with a really bizarre Picker behaviour. If you have time, take a look at https://gist.github.com/Gujci/91d8a72225425c5325ca108cc9494ae8

Comment: @gujci That's quite some fancy footwork you used there! I made some progress on my side and basically hit the exact same issue as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but after spending some time on it, I think it's worth summarizing my findings in case it helps somebody. To summarize, I was trying to set the second Picker depending on what the selection of the first Picker was.

If you run the code that I pasted as is, you will get an out of bounds. This is only the case if I set `@State private var dimensionSelection = 1` and the second array is larger than the first array. If you start with smaller array, you will be fine which you can observe by setting `@State private var dimensionSelection = 0`. There are a few ways to solve this.

1. Always start with the smallest array (Not great)
2. Instead of using an array of `String`, use an array of objects implementing Identifiable. this is the solution proposed by fuzz above. This got past the out of bound array exception. In my case though, I needed to specify the id parameter in the ForEach parameters.
3. Extend String to implement `Identifiable` as long as your strings are all different (which works in my trivial example). This is the solution proposed by gujci and his proposed solution looks much more elegant than mine, so I encourage you to take a look. Note that this to work in my own example. I suspect it might be  due to how we built the arrays differently.

HOWEVER, once you get past these issues, it will still not work, You will hit an issue that appears be some kind of bug where the Picker keep adding new elements. My impression is that to get around this, one would have to destroy the Picker every time, but since I'm still learning Swift and SwiftUI, I haven't gotten round doing this.

Comment: This is indeed frustrating. I've a picker where the first logical option is to show minutes and then hours. Your first point does seem to be true since going from hours (24) to mins(60) doesn't crash but the other way around is failing.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to make sure according to Apple's documentation that the array elements are `Identifiable` as you've mentioned.

Then you'll want to use `ForEach` like this:

```
struct Dimension: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

var temperatureUnits = [
    Dimension(id: 0, name: "Celsius"),
    Dimension(id: 1, name: "Fahrenheit"),
    Dimension(id: 2, name: "Kelvin")
]

ForEach(temperatureUnits) { dimension in
    Text(dimension.name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was going to add this, but didn't want to make my post too long. I tried something similar, but it is still failing with the same error. I made an array of arrays of Dimension, each Dimension with an individual id and then iterating like the inner array. The issue can be seen when running the code. It starts with Length selected and if you change to Temperature it crashes due to the array being of a different size.

Comment: `String` can conform to `Identifiable` like `extension String: Identifiable { public var id: String { self } }` as long as the names differ, it's ok for testing.